# Unhiding menu item

Tags: javascript, html

I have used this code for hide a menu item for particular on click option,

```
function hideMacroPairElement() {

    if(document.getElementById('macroPairList').style.display!='none') {

      document.getElementById('macroPairList').style.display='none';
    }

    else
    {


    if(document.getElementById('macroPairList').style.display=='none') {

      document.getElementById('macroPairList').style.display='block';
    }
}}
```

**HTML:**

```
<hr>
    <ul id="menuPanelSubListGroup3" class="collapse librePanelSubListGroupItem">
      <li class="list-group-item librePanelListGroupItem">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#menuPanelSubListGroup4" onclick="hideMacroPairElement()">
          <span>SPS</span>
          <b class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down">
          </b>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

But I want to unhide that menu item for all other on click option.

Comment: Show your HTML and your click event code.

Comment: <ul id="menuPanelSubListGroup3" class="collapse librePanelSubListGroupItem">
                                       <li class="list-group-item librePanelListGroupItem">
                                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#menuPanelSubListGroup4" onclick="hideMacroPairElement()">
                                         <span>SPS</span>
                                         <b class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></b>
                    </a>

Comment: I want to hide macro pair menu item for SPS but want to unhide for all other menu items.

Comment: edit the question and put the code in the question - not in a comment

Comment: The `macroPairList` ID is not included in your HTML.

Comment: P.S. Spelling error. Edit `HMTL` to `HTML`

Comment: yes i know i'm little bit confused please help me out with full code snippet Alex.

Comment: What do you mean with "But I want to unhide that menu item for all other on click option." What "all other" means?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs You can't just [try to add a jQuery tag and *"a jQuery solution is also desirable"*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20083468) to the question because your answer uses jQuery. OP has already specifically said [they want a JavaScript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963609/javascript-html-css-bootstrap/50963832#comment88924357_50963832), not jQuery.

Comment: @NickA ah my bad, in response to other answer, OP said they wanted a jQuery solution - I see now comment edited to use JavaScript :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Comment was never edited, you must have misread it, edited comments have a pencil mark after the timestamp :), no harm done though

Comment: @NickA shiz you're right ... o.o must've been fiending for jQuery xD and indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try hiding it by class and unhiding it by id.

Using javascript could be something like this:

```html
function hideMacroPairElement() {
    var macroPairListElements = document.getElementsByClassName("macroPairList");
    for(var i = 0; i < macroPairListElements.length; i++){
        macroPairListElements[i].style.display='block';
    }
    document.getElementsById("macroPairListElement").style.display='none';
}
```

Using jQuery could be something like this:

```html
function hideMacroPairElement() {
    $('.macroPairList').css('display', 'block');
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
}
```

Comment: There is no `jQuery` tag in his question. I'm sure he wants to do it in vanilla JS.

Comment: i want to do in JavaScript

Comment: Javascript solution added.

Answer (score 0):

your id macroPairList is not mentioned at your HTML code.
try to use simple code

```
document.getElementById('YourID').addEventListener('click',hideData);
function hideData(){
    document.getElementById('YourIDtoHide').style.display="none";
}
```

Comment: Same id name can be use for two different menu items?

Comment: No, you need to create different IDs